# Misunderstanding of the shift rule's proof for sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I was trying to prove some properties of convergent sequences when I found that [pdf file](https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/oleg_zaboronski/analysisi/notes-ma131_ch3.pdf) which mentions and gives the proof of the shift rule (page 5 of the document):

> **Theorem** *Shift rule*
>
> Let $N$ be a natural number. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence. Then $a_n \rightarrow a$ if and only if the "shifted" sequence $a_{N+n} \rightarrow a$.
>
> **Proof**. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. If $(a_n) \rightarrow a$ we know there exists $N_1$ such that $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ whenever $n > N_1$. When $n > N_1$, we see that $N+n > N_1$, therefore $|a_{N+n}-a| < \epsilon$. Hence $(a_{N+n}) \rightarrow a$.
>
> Conversely, suppose that $(a_{N+n}) \rightarrow a$. Then there exists $N_2$ such that $|a_{N+n}-a|< \epsilon$ whenever $n > N_2$. When $n > N+N_2$ then $n-N > N_2$ so $|a_n-a|=|a_{N+(n-N)}-a| < \epsilon$. Hence $(a_n) \rightarrow a$. $\square$

**While I understand the first part of the proof, I don't understand the second one.**

First of all, it took me some time to understand why they say:

> Then there exists $N_2$ such that $|a_{N+n}-a|< \epsilon$ whenever $n > N_2$.

It seemed more logical to me to write "whenever $N+n > N_2$", so I wrote $(z_n)=(a_{N+n})$ for more clarity.

Then, they consider the cases where $n > N+N_2$. And I understand their argument, but what I don't get is: how to conclude the proof if $N+N_2 > n > N_2 ?$ Because the statement should be true for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, so I don't see why we couldn't have such a case.

Finally, I don't really understand the whole second part as it seems counterintuitive ; if this second part is true, I feel like the definition of a convergent sequence should be something like: "a sequence $(x_n)$ converges towards $x$ if and only if there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, |x_n - x| < \epsilon$". Of course this is wrong, but that's the feeling I get when I look at the second part of the proof. Shouldn't we have, in the theorem, an implication instead of an "if and only if"? I'm confused.

Thanks in advance for the help! (And sorry if the answers to my questions are obvious ; nothing is obvious for me.)

Answer (score 0):

"... whenever $n>N_2$" is precisely what the definition of convergence gives us. Recall that we consider the sequence $(b_n)$ where $b_n:=a_{n+N}$. Now $b_n\to a$ translates into:

> For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_2\in \Bbb N$ such that $|b_n-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_2$.

i.e.,

> For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_2\in \Bbb N$ such that $|a_{n+N}-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N_2$.

After this, we may consider $N_3:=N+N_2$ (which depends only on $\epsilon$) and notice that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N_3$. As we can find such $N_3$ for every $\epsilon>0$, we have shown
$$\forall \epsilon>0\colon\exists N_3\in\Bbb N\colon \forall n>N_3\colon|a_n-a|<\epsilon $$
which is precisely the definition of $a_n\to a$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, what I don't understand is why it is sufficient to prove that it converges for $n > N_3$, while there could still be some $n$ between $N_2$ and $N_3$ (that is: $N_3 > n > N_2$) for which nothing has (apparently) been proved yet. I'm obviously missing something about this but I can't find what it is.